# How to create multiple user account types in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I wanna create multiple user account types for my site like Paypal or like this.
Users can choose their account types to register. Here is example picture:
[image]

But in drupal I only see 2 account types, anonymous and authentication. How can I add more? And each account type has different fields to input information.

Thanks you!

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add roles to users in `People > Permissions > Roles`. From there there are a lot of ways to add input fields depending on the role of the user.